# Divisibility of sum of multinomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, soft-question

Let $n, m$ and $t$ be positive integers. Define the multi-family of sequences
$$S(n,m,t)=\sum_{k_1+\cdots+k_n=m}\binom{m}{k_1,\dots,k_n}^t$$
where the sum runs over non-negative integers $k_1,\dots,k_n$. These numbers are related to average distances (from the origin) of uniform unit-step random walks on the plane.

> **QUESTION.** Is it always true that $n$ divides $S(n,m,t)$?

Observe that $S(n,m,1)=n^m$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We count the number of $t$-tuples $(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_t)$ of the colorings of $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ with $n$ given colors, for which any two colorings use the same multisets of colors. If $M$ is the number of such tuples in which 1 is colored red in the coloring $\xi_1$ (red is one of our $n$ colors), the total number of $t$-tuples equals $n\cdot M$.